# Tikz: drawing points for MIMO-System

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have following picture:

[image: MIMO]

and want to replace the middle arrow with dots as is indicated on the following image:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tikz}    
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (System) [draw,minimum size=24mm] {$\sum$};
\coordinate[above left = of System.west] (a1);
\coordinate[below = of a1] (a2);
\coordinate[below = of a2] (a3);
\coordinate[above right= of System.east] (b1);
\foreach \i [count=\xi from 1] in {2,...,5}
    \coordinate[below=of b\xi] (b\i);
\foreach \i [count=\xi from 1] in {$u_1$,$u_2$,$u_3$}
\draw[-latex'] (a\xi) node[left] {\i} -- (a\xi-| System.west);
\foreach \i [count=\xi from 1] in {$y_1$,$y_2$,$y_3$}
    \draw[-latex'] (System.east |- b\xi) -- (b\xi) node[right] {\i};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Strukturbild eines MIMO-Systems}
\label{fig:mimo}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and rename the last one `yn` and `un`, for indicating that there can be n-in or outputs. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Please provide a full compilable document. It has to start with `\documentclass`, end with `\end{document}` and compile without errors, thanks.

Comment: sorry, already done

Comment: I took liberty in move added image (that question is more clear) and revert your originally code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Packages and libraries had to be loaded in document preamble: first package, than its libraries!
- For your MWE are missed two libraries (`arrows`, `positioning`)
- Instead of `arrows` I suggest to use `arrows.meta` as I do in MWE below

**Edit:**
Considering your comment below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 6mm and 12mm
                        ]
\node (System) [draw,minimum size=24mm] {$\sum$};
%
\coordinate[above  left = of System.west, label=left:$u_1$] (a1);
\coordinate[       left = of System.west, label=left:$u_2$] (a2);
\coordinate[below  left = of System.west, label=left:$u_3$] (a3);
%
\coordinate[above right = of System.east, label=right:$y_1$] (b1);
\coordinate[      right = of System.east, label={[xshift=-4mm]left:$\vdots$}] (b2);
\coordinate[below right = of System.east, label=right:$y_n$] (b3);
%
\foreach \i in {1,2,3}
    \draw[-Latex]   (a\i) -- (a\i-| System.west);
\foreach \i in {1,3}
    \draw[-Latex]   (b\i -| System.east) -- (b\i);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Strukturbild eines MIMO-Systems}
\label{fig:mimo}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

above MWE now gives:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! but how do i get the 3 Dots like in the picture i put on in my first post?

Comment: @ekaologik, see edited answer. Apparently in the first I misread your question.

Answer (score 3):

One could add little circles using the `calc` library:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,positioning,arrows,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (System) [draw,minimum size=24mm] {$\sum$};
\coordinate[above left = of System.west] (a1);
\coordinate[below = of a1] (a2);
\coordinate[below = of a2] (a3);
\coordinate[above right= of System.east] (b1);
\foreach \i [count=\xi from 1] in {2,...,5}
    \coordinate[below=of b\xi] (b\i);
\foreach \i [count=\xi from 1] in {$u_1$,$u_2$}
\draw[-latex'] (a\xi) node[left] {\i} -- (a\xi-| System.west);
\draw[-latex'] (a3) node[left] {$u_n$} -- (a3-| System.west);
%\foreach \i [count=\xi from 1] in {$y_1$,$y_2$,$y_3$}
%    \draw[-latex'] (System.east |- b\xi) -- (b\xi) node[right] {\i};
\draw[-latex'] (System.east |- b1) -- (b1) node[right] {$y_1$};
\draw[-latex'] (System.east |- b3) -- (b3) node[right] {$y_n$};
\fill ($(b1)+(-0.5,-0.75)$) circle (0.03cm);   
\fill ($(b1)+(-0.5,-1)$) circle (0.03cm);   
\fill ($(b1)+(-0.5,-1.25)$) circle (0.03cm);   
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Strukturbild eines MIMO-Systems}
\label{fig:mimo}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]