# Tikz: Positioning of Arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

i got an Problem to get the right position of the 2 Arrows on the right side. I want them to be "in the middle".

[image: GSM]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (System) [draw,minimum size=24mm] {Motor};
    \coordinate[above left = of System.west] (a1);
    \coordinate[below = 7mm of a1] (a2);
    \coordinate[below = 7mm of a2] (a3);
    \coordinate[below = 6.5mm of a3] (a4);
    \coordinate[above right= of System.east] (b1);
    \foreach \i [count=\xi from 1] in {2,...,5}
        \coordinate[below=of b\xi] (b\i);
    \foreach \i [count=\xi from 1] in {$u_\mathrm{a}$,$i_\mathrm{a}$,$u_\mathrm{f}$,$i_\mathrm{f}$}
    \draw[-latex'] (a\xi) node[left] {\i} -- (a\xi-| System.west);
    \foreach \i [count=\xi from 1] in {$n$,$M$}
        \draw[-latex'] (System.east |- b\xi) -- (b\xi) node[right] {\i};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{GSM als Motor}
    \label{fig:gsmmotor}
\end{minipage}
\qquad
\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (System) [draw,minimum size=24mm] {Generator};
        \coordinate[above left = of System.west] (a1);
        \coordinate[below = 7mm of a1] (a2);
        \coordinate[below = 7mm of a2] (a3);
        \coordinate[below = 6.5mm of a3] (a4);
        \coordinate[above right= of System.east] (b1);
        \foreach \i [count=\xi from 1] in {2,...,5}
            \coordinate[below=of b\xi] (b\i);
        \foreach \i [count=\xi from 1] in {$n$,$M$,$u_\mathrm{f}$,$i_\mathrm{f}$}
        \draw[-latex'] (a\xi) node[left] {\i} -- (a\xi-| System.west);
        \foreach \i [count=\xi from 1] in {$u_a$,$i_a$}
            \draw[-latex'] (System.east |- b\xi) -- (b\xi) node[right] {\i};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{GSM als Generator}
        \label{fig:gsmgenerator}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

how can i center the arrows?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code is not compileable. some TikZ library are missing. Please update your question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503023/tikz-drawing-points-for-mimo-system/503027#503027):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm and 12mm
                        ]
\node (System) [draw,minimum size=24mm] {Motor};
%
\coordinate[above  left = of System.west, label=left:$u_a$]   (a2);
\coordinate[above   = 6mm of a2, label=left:$i_a$]            (a1);
\coordinate[below  left = of System.west, label=left:$u_f$] (a3);
\coordinate[below   = 6mm of a3, label=left:$u_f$]          (a4);
%
\coordinate[above right = of System.east, label=right:$n$] (b1);
\coordinate[below right = of System.east, label=right:$M$] (b2);
%
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}{\draw[-Latex]   (a\i) -- (a\i -| System.west);}
\foreach \i in {1,2}{\draw[-Latex]   (b\i -| System.east) -- (b\i);}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{GSM als Motor}
\label{fig:mimo}
\end{minipage}
\hfil
\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm and 12mm
                        ]
\node (System) [draw,minimum size=24mm] {Generator};
%
\coordinate[above  left = of System.west, label=left:$n$]   (a2);
\coordinate[above   = 6mm of a2, label=left:$M$]            (a1);
\coordinate[below  left = of System.west, label=left:$u_3$] (a3);
\coordinate[below   = 6mm of a3, label=left:$u_2$]          (a4);
%
\coordinate[above right = of System.east, label=right:$u_a$] (b1);
\coordinate[below right = of System.east, label=right:$i_a$] (b2);
%
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}{\draw[-Latex]   (a\i) -- (a\i -| System.west);}
\foreach \i in {1,2}{\draw[-Latex]   (b\i -| System.east) -- (b\i);}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{GSM als Generator}
\label{fig:mimo}
\end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. To place two arrows in the *middle*, I considered that you wanted *(I hope I'm not mistaken)* these two arrows to point to the *third* and *two thirds* of the side. 
   To do this, I use the `calc` library, which allows me to locate these third parties precisely:

   ```
   \coordinate (u) at ($(System.north east)!.3333!(System.south east)$);
   \coordinate (i) at ($(System.north east)!.6666!(System.south east)$);
   ```

[image: screenshot]

2. To place the `arrow` horizontally, I first place the text to the `right` of each **third** of the System node, then draw the arrow with the `edge` syntax:

   ```
         \node[right =of u]{$n$}edge[<-](u);  
         \node[right =of i]{$M$}edge[<-](i);
   ```
3. I took the liberty of placing the two figures side by side with TikZ. To do this, I placed each of them in a `scope` environment and shifted the second one with`xshift=7cm`. I have given a name to each scope environment: `local bounding box=motor` and `local bounding box=generator`, which allows me to place the text underneath very easily.

   ```
   \begin{scope}[local bounding box=motor]
   % code for figure 1
   % ...
   \end{scope}
   \node [anchor=north,text width=6cm]at (motor.south) {\captionof{figure}{GSM als Motor}}; % caption text
   ```

   \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm,local bounding box=generator]
   % code for figure 2
   % ....
   \end{scope}
    \node [anchor=north,text width=6cm]at (generator.south) {\captionof{figure}{GSM als Generator}}; % caption text
4. In order not to manually number the figures, as underlined by *Torbjørn T* in my first solution, I use the `capt-of` package which allows to number non floating objects.
5. So, I commented on all the lines of your code that I no longer use (without deleting them).

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz,capt-of}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,positioning,arrows,calc}
\begin{document}


%\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
%\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=motor]
    \node (System) [draw,minimum size=24mm] {Motor};
    \coordinate[above left = of System.west] (a1);
    \coordinate[below = 7mm of a1] (a2);
    \coordinate[below = 7mm of a2] (a3);
    \coordinate[below = 6.5mm of a3] (a4);
    \coordinate[above right= of System.east] (b1);
    \foreach \i [count=\xi from 1] in {2,...,5}
        \coordinate[below=of b\xi] (b\i);
    \foreach \i [count=\xi from 1] in {$u_\mathrm{a}$,$i_\mathrm{a}$,$u_\mathrm{f}$,$i_\mathrm{f}$}
        \draw[-latex'] (a\xi) node[left] {\i} -- (a\xi-| System.west);
%   \foreach \i [count=\xi from 1] in {$n$,$M$}
%        \draw[-latex'] (System.east |- b\xi) -- (b\xi) node[right] {\i};   

    \coordinate (u) at ($(System.north east)!.3333!(System.south east)$);
    \coordinate (i) at ($(System.north east)!.6666!(System.south east)$);
    \node[right =of u]{$n$}edge[<-](u);  
    \node[right =of i]{$M$}edge[<-](i);    
    \end{scope}
    %\node[anchor=north,yshift=-5mm] at (motor.south){Figure\,1: GSM als Motor};
   \node [anchor=north,text width=6cm]at (motor.south) {\captionof{figure}{GSM als Motor}};
%    \end{tikzpicture}
%    \caption{GSM als Motor}
%    \label{fig:gsmmotor}
%\end{minipage}
%\qquad
%\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
%    \begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[xshift=7cm,local bounding box=generator]
    \node (System) [draw,minimum size=24mm] {Generator};
    \coordinate[above left = of System.west] (a1);
    \coordinate[below = 7mm of a1] (a2);
    \coordinate[below = 7mm of a2] (a3);
    \coordinate[below = 6.5mm of a3] (a4);
    \coordinate[above right= of System.east] (b1);
    \foreach \i [count=\xi from 1] in {2,...,5}
            \coordinate[below=of b\xi] (b\i);
    \foreach \i [count=\xi from 1] in {$n$,$M$,$u_\mathrm{f}$,$i_\mathrm{f}$}
        \draw[-latex'] (a\xi) node[left] {\i} -- (a\xi-| System.west);
%   \foreach \i [count=\xi from 1] in {$u_a$,$i_a$}
%       \draw[-latex'] (System.east |- b\xi) -- (b\xi) node[right] {\i};

    \coordinate (u) at ($(System.north east)!.3333!(System.south east)$);
    \coordinate (i) at ($(System.north east)!.6666!(System.south east)$);
    \node[right =of u]{$u_a$}edge[<-](u);  
    \node[right =of i]{$i_a$}edge[<-](i);
 \end{scope}
%\node[anchor=north,yshift=-5mm] at (generator.south){Figure\,2: GSM als Generator};
\node [anchor=north,text width=6cm]at (generator.south) {\captionof{figure}{GSM als Generator}};
\end{tikzpicture}
%        \caption{GSM als Generator}
        \label{fig:gsmgenerator}
%\end{minipage}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem with doing the captions that way is that the numbering is done manually (definitely troublesome if there are other figures in the document), and that you cannot cross-reference them. However, you can put a `\caption` in a `node`, if `text width` is set, e.g. `\node [text width=5cm] {\caption{Stuff \label{foo}}};`.

Comment: Indeed, I hadn't thought of that because I've never written a big document with LaTeX. The advantage of doing as I do is that the placement of the figures is much easier and more accurate. Each advantage has a drawback, your way of doing things is more adapted to a large document, for a small one mine is easier to implement. The PO now has the choice, let him choose.

Comment: As I said, it's possible to use your method for positioning, *and* have numbered captions via `\caption`. Even for a small document I wouldn't have manually numbered figures.

Comment: Personally, I never need to number the figures because I call them by their name (square ABCD, triangle EFG, parallelogram OPQR, etc). To teach in Junior High School, this is sufficient. But if one day I need to do it, I'll think of you. :)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Since you have highlighted this problem of manual floating numbering, I fix my solution using the `capt-of` package. One thing I don't understand is that the compilation fails if you don't specify the size of the text `text width=6cm`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any libraries for that, nor complicated commands. With `pos=<fraction>` you can add a coordinate at some factional position of the respective edges, and then add the arrows and nodes. All this is as simple as saying

```
\path (System.south west) -- (System.north west)  
    foreach \X/\Z  in {0.05/i_f,0.35/u_f,0.65/M,0.95/n}
    {coordinate[pos=\X](aux)  (aux) edge[latex-] ++ (-1,0) 
    node[left=1cm]{$\Z$}};
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (System) [draw,minimum size=24mm] {Motor};
    \path (System.south west) -- (System.north west)  
    foreach \X/\Z  in {0.05/i_f,0.35/u_f,0.65/M,0.95/n}
    {coordinate[pos=\X](aux)  (aux) edge[latex-] ++ (-1,0) 
    node[left=1cm]{$\Z$}};
    \path (System.south east) -- (System.north east)  
    foreach \X/\Z in {0.3/u_a,0.7/i_a}
    {coordinate[pos=\X] (aux) (aux) edge[-latex] ++ (1,0) node[right=1cm]{$\Z$}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{GSM als Motor.}
 \label{fig:gsmmotor}
\end{minipage}
\qquad
\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (System) [draw,minimum size=24mm] {Motor};
    \path (System.south west) -- (System.north west)  
    foreach \X/\Z  in {0.05/i_f,0.35/u_f,0.65/M,0.95/n}
    {coordinate[pos=\X](aux)  (aux) edge[latex-] ++ (-1,0) 
    node[left=1cm]{$\Z$}};
    \path (System.south east) -- (System.north east)  
    foreach \X/\Z in {0.3/u_a,0.7/i_a}
    {coordinate[pos=\X] (aux) (aux) edge[-latex] ++ (1,0) node[right=1cm]{$\Z$}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{GSM als Generator.}
  \label{fig:gsmgenerator}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]